# Images are messing with my lists

Tags: github, markdown, wiki

I am doing a list and in the middle in the list I need to put an image. The problem is, that it messes my list up.
I have something like this

```
1. element 1
2. element 2
![](imagesurl)
3. element 3
```

but it displays something like this

> 1. element 1
> 2. element 2
>
> image
>
> 1. element 3

I need it to display something like this:

> 1. element 1
> 2. element 2
>
>    image
> 3. element 3

does anyone of you know how to fix this?

Comment: That is the correct rendering for the source text you have. What output are you expecting? You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40135685/edit) your question and add that information.

Comment: The output I'm expecting is something like this:                                        element 1
element 2 image
element 3

I need the list to keep it's order. I don't want it to start from 1

Comment: Your expected and actual output were rendering exactly the same. I believe my edits properly reflect your intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you desire your image to be on a separate line by itself, then you need to have it surrounded by blank lines. And if you want to nest an item in a list item, then you must indent that item one level (4 spaces):

```
1. element 1
2. element 2

    ![](imagesurl)

3. element 3
```

The above renders as:

> 1. element 1
> 2. element 2
>
>    image
> 3. element 3